# select string over date in python panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to take the highest value from my data here. The last_release field got the string 'now' and i want 'now' to be picked over other dates if my code encounters it. Currently the code picks the most recent date but not the 'now' string. All that i tried to fix this issue is not materializing. Any help would be of tremendous help.

Code:

```
df['last_release']  = pd.to_datetime(df['last_release'])
df['first_release'] = pd.to_datetime(df['first_release'])
df['rating_level'] = pd.Categorical(df['rating_level'], ['low', 'medium', 'high', 'critical'], ordered=True)
df['security_level'] = pd.Categorical(df['security_level'], ['minor', 'material', 'moderate', 'severe', 'supersevere'], ordered=True)

agg_dict = {'security_level': 'max', 'rating': 'max', 'rating_level': 'max',
            'first_release': 'min', 'last_release': 'max', 'score': 'max'}
            
out = df.groupby(['company', 'product'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg(agg_dict)
```

| company | product | security_level | rating | rating_level | first_release | last_release | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| google | mobile | minor | TRUE | critical | 04/11/2020 | now | 0.5 |
| google | os | moderate | FALSE | medium | 09/05/2019 | 03/20/2021 | 0.009 |
| google | os | minor | FALSE | low | 09/04/2019 | 05/11/2020 | 19 |
| google | tv | severe | TRUE | high | 08/11/2020 | 03/04/2021 |  |
| google | mobile | supersevere | FALSE | medium | 04/06/2015 | 08/19/2020 | 2.4 |
| google | mobile | minor | FALSE | high | 08/08/2019 | 08/19/2020 | 1.3 |
| apple | iphone | minor | TRUE | low | 02/03/2020 | now | 3 |
| apple | iphone | material | TRUE | medium | 01/21/2018 | 03/04/2021 | 6 |
| apple | iwatch | material | FALSE | low | 04/11/2015 | 08/13/2020 | 8 |
| apple | iphone | material | TRUE | medium | 10/20/2020 | 03/19/2021 | 5 |
| dell | laptop | minor | FALSE | low | 01/05/2021 | 03/20/2021 | 1 |

Output:

| company | product | security_level | rating | rating_level | first_release | last_release | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| google | mobile | supersevere | TRUE | critical | 04/06/2015 | now | 2.4 |
| google | os | moderate | FALSE | medium | 09/04/2019 | 03/20/2021 | 19 |
| google | tv | severe | TRUE | high | 08/11/2020 | 03/04/2021 |  |
| apple | iphone | material | TRUE | medium | 01/21/2018 | now | 6 |
| apple | iwatch | material | FALSE | low | 04/11/2015 | 08/13/2020 | 8 |
| dell | laptop | minor | FALSE | low | 01/05/2021 | 03/20/2021 | 1 |

Comment: How about replacing every `now` with `date`?

Comment: I didn't completely get your side. But are you trying to say to include 'now' exclusively with date?

Comment: Yes, replace every `now` with appropriate date. (sorry, if you tried this already)

Comment: i need to retain the 'now'.

Comment: then, replace `date` with `now` after you're done with your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be 100% consistent in how you switch between strings, dates and strings and it's simple.

```
fmt = "%m/%d/%Y"
now = pd.to_datetime("now").strftime(fmt)
df["last_release"] = df["last_release"].str.replace("now",now)

df['last_release']  = pd.to_datetime(df['last_release'])
df['first_release'] = pd.to_datetime(df['first_release'])
df['rating_level'] = pd.Categorical(df['rating_level'], ['low', 'medium', 'high', 'critical'], ordered=True)
df['security_level'] = pd.Categorical(df['security_level'], ['minor', 'material', 'moderate', 'severe', 'supersevere'], ordered=True)

agg_dict = {'security_level': 'max', 'rating': 'max', 'rating_level': 'max',
            'first_release': 'min', 'last_release': 'max', 'score': 'max'}
            
out = df.groupby(['company', 'product'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg(agg_dict)
out["last_release"] = out["last_release"].dt.strftime(fmt).str.replace(now,"now")
```

|  | company | product | security_level | rating | rating_level | first_release | last_release | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | google | mobile | supersevere | True | critical | 2015-04-06 00:00:00 | now | 2.4 |
| 1 | google | os | moderate | False | medium | 2019-09-04 00:00:00 | 03/20/2021 | 19 |
| 2 | google | tv | severe | True | high | 2020-08-11 00:00:00 | 03/04/2021 | nan |
| 3 | apple | iphone | material | True | medium | 2018-01-21 00:00:00 | now | 6 |
| 4 | apple | iwatch | material | False | low | 2015-04-11 00:00:00 | 08/13/2020 | 8 |
| 5 | dell | laptop | minor | False | low | 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | 03/20/2021 | 1 |

Comment: Thanks Rob. I had to make subtle changes to reach my results. But your code served as the spine to that. Cheers mate